# Display field in profil.php

Tags: wordpress

I using this code to add 3 fields in inscription form Wordpress, and it's work. Now i want to display this in profil.php so that users can modify :

```
add_user_meta($userId,'phone','text');
add_user_meta($userId,'adress','text2');
add_user_meta($userId,'size','text3');
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: From this article you can understand how to add custom field to profile/edit user page in backend - https://wpengineer.com/2173/custom-fields-wordpress-user-profile/

Comment: Thank you, but me i have several fields, is there an example with several fields?

Comment: yes you can use any number of fields same code will help you to add it, now its up to you how you work with it